# What is the term for a collection of vertices in a graph that are all mutually connected to one another?

Tags: graph-theory

Given the following graph:

[image: A graph]

What's the term to describe the fact that vertices `1`, `2`, and `5` are all mutually connected to one another (as in `1` is connected to `2` and `5`, `2` is connected to `1` and `5`, etc.)? I'm trying to lookup algorithms to determine when a given set of vertices are all connected to each other (not via other vertices, but with direct connections).

Comment: The vertices in a connected component are all connected to adjacent vertices and to each other through paths.

Comment: You are looking for subgraphs that are complete. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph

Comment: clique of size n , in this case, 3.